# How to add icons or emoji in django admin buttons

Tags: python, django, django-admin, icons, emoji

So I have some buttons in django admin and I need to add something like that: ⬅️➡️↩️↪️ to my admin buttons, but I have 0 idea how to do this and I feel like I am the first ever person to ask that question on the internet, google didnt help :)) Can you guys suggest something?